# WCCA analysis - Induction selection - Mismatch with recommendation at low current values

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm, frequency, switching

I'm performing the WCCA analysis of a 3.3V buck regulator(AP64200Q).
Datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64200Q.pdf

In the current circuit:Vin=24V,Vout=3.3V,Max.current=300mA so DeltaIl=100mA(~30% ripple) & fsw=500khz
**So L~56uH**
[image: Inductor selection formula]

whereas in vendor provided spreadsheet, the recommendation is around 15uH
[image]

*In low current consumption conditions (our case), the regulator switches from PWM to PFM. But how does the induction selection formula get modified during this condition?*
[image]